# Stored Procedure no funciona como esperaba

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Estoy tratando de ejecutar el procedimiento a través de triggers. Tanto cuando se insertan datos en x tabla, como cuando se actualizan o se borran. Pero cuando lo ejecuto no funciona como debería y no se por qué.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`aaronibio`@`%` PROCEDURE `actualizar_parmetros_terrarios_global`(IN especiecambiada BIGINT, IN idterrario BIGINT)
BEGIN  
    UPDATE terrarios t
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            et.idterrario,
            MIN(e.temperatura_maxima) AS temp_max, 
            MAX(e.temperatura_minima) AS temp_min,
            MIN(e.temperatura_hib_maxima) AS temp_hib_max,
            MAX(e.temperatura_hib_minima) AS temp_hib_min,
            MIN(e.humedad_maxima) AS hum_max,
            MAX(e.humedad_minima) AS hum_min,
            MIN(e.horas_luz) AS horas_luz,
            MIN(e.horas_luz_hib) AS horas_luz_hib
        FROM especies e 
        JOIN especie_terrario et ON e.id = et.idespecie 
        WHERE e.id = especiecambiada -- Filtrar por la especie pasada por parámetro
        GROUP BY et.idterrario
    ) subq ON t.id = subq.idterrario
    SET 
        t.temperatura_maxima = CASE WHEN t.id = idterrario THEN subq.temp_max ELSE t.temperatura_maxima END,
        t.temperatura_minima = CASE WHEN t.id = idterrario THEN subq.temp_min ELSE t.temperatura_minima END,
        t.temperatura_maxima_hiber = CASE WHEN t.id = idterrario THEN subq.temp_hib_max ELSE t.temperatura_maxima_hiber END,
        t.temperatura_minima_hiber = CASE WHEN t.id = idterrario THEN subq.temp_hib_min ELSE t.temperatura_minima_hiber END,
        t.humedad_maxima = CASE WHEN t.id = idterrario THEN subq.hum_max ELSE t.humedad_maxima END,
        t.humedad_minima = CASE WHEN t.id = idterrario THEN subq.hum_min ELSE t.humedad_minima END,
        t.horas_luz = CASE WHEN t.id = idterrario THEN subq.horas_luz ELSE t.horas_luz END,
        t.horas_luz_hiber = CASE WHEN t.id = idterrario THEN subq.horas_luz_hib ELSE t.horas_luz_hiber END
    WHERE t.id = idterrario; -- Filtrar por el ID del terrario pasado por parámetro
END
```

En teoría, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando haga el CUD se actualice el terrario con el id pasado por parámetro con los máximos y mínimos de todas las especies que tenga dicho terrario según la tabla especies_terrario.

Pero realmente no pasa nada. O al menos yo no veo ningún tipo de cambio y los trigger únicamente llaman a los procedimientos como hago el resto de triggers, como por ejemplo este:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`aaronibio`@`%` TRIGGER `especie_terrario_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `especie_terrario` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    CALL qtech.actualizar_parametros_terrario(NEW.idespecie, NEW.idterrario);
END
```

Cuando quito una especie y pongo otra en un terrario, se queda con los valores antiguos. Nunca cambia.

Comment: Ya nos explicaste qué esperas que pase. Te falta mostrarnos los triggers y mostrarnos qué es lo que está pasando cuando se ejecutan

Comment: Ups, perdón, ahora edito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes no uno, sino varios problemas.

- El problema más evidente está en la manera de filtrar de tu consulta, ya que en la consulta donde obtienes máximos y mínimos solamente estás obteniendo el registro de la especie que te pasan por parámetro, pero en la descripción dices que quieres actualizar el terrario con todas las especies que existen en él.

  Esto es relativamente fácil de arreglar, pues lo que necesitas es determinar en qué terrario está la especie y luego obtener TODAS las especies en dicho terrario.
- Otro problema es la forma en que haces un join de la tabla de terrarios con el resultado de la consulta, que te devuelve todos los terrarios a los que pertenece la especie, que te hace actualizar muchas veces el registro (y por ello has escrito las sentencias *case*. En realidad esa consulta debiera devolver un solo registro. El del terrario que te interesa.
- Este es un poco más sutil y se va a dar solo cuando borren una especie o cuando borren su registro de pertenencia a un terrario. Es decir, el enfoque actual, si se implementa bien, funciona para las inserciones y actualizaciones.

  El problema con los borrados es que si lanzas el trigger después del borrado, ya no podrás encontrar el id del terrario al que pertenecía la especie, pues ya no existen los registros en la base de datos.

  Por otro lado, si lo lanzas antes del borrado, la consulta que haces para obtener máximos y mínimos aún tomará en cuenta la especie que justo se está borrando y eso puede afectar tus resultados. Realmente quieres obtener los resultados sin dicha especie.

  Hay varias maneras de resolver este problema... puedes enviar más información al SP, para que sepa si se está borrando y entonces excluya a la especie de la consulta, o puedes tener SP's especializados para cada caso, o puedes determinar mejor el ID del terrario dentro del trigger y pasar al SP dicho ID.
- Llegados a este punto, debemos considerar la posibilidad de que una actualización en la tabla especies_terrario pueda *mover* una especie de un terrario a otro, en ese caso habrá que actualizar ambos.

Mi sugerencia es que a este SP le pases solo el ID del terrario, y que resuelvas estas cuestiones en los triggers de marras, por ejemplo cuando se agrega/modifica/borra un registro en `especies_terrario`, o cuando se actualiza un registro en la tabla `especies`, etc.

Finalmente, yo escribiría este SP más o menos como:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`aaronibio`@`%` PROCEDURE `actualizar_parmetros_terrarios_global`(IN idterrario BIGINT)
BEGIN  
  update terrarios t
           cross join (select   MIN(e.temperatura_maxima) AS temp_max
                              , MAX(e.temperatura_minima) AS temp_min
                              , MIN(e.temperatura_hib_maxima) AS temp_hib_max
                              , MAX(e.temperatura_hib_minima) AS temp_hib_min
                              , MIN(e.humedad_maxima) AS hum_max
                              , MAX(e.humedad_minima) AS hum_min
                              , MIN(e.horas_luz) AS horas_luz
                              , MIN(e.horas_luz_hib) AS horas_luz_hib
                         from especie_terrario et
                              inner join especies e on e.id = et.idespecie 
                        where et.idterrario = idterrario
                      ) subq 
     set   t.temperatura_maxima = subq.temp_max
         , t.temperatura_minima = subq.temp_min
         , t.temperatura_maxima_hiber = subq.temp_hib_max
         , t.temperatura_minima_hiber = subq.temp_hib_min
         , t.humedad_maxima = subq.hum_max
         , t.humedad_minima = subq.hum_min
         , t.horas_luz = subq.horas_luz
         , t.horas_luz_hiber = subq.horas_luz_hib
   where t.id = idterrario; 
END
```

Y me aseguraría de llamarlo siempre después de que los cambios se reflejan en las tablas de la base de datos.

Comment: Pues en el resto de triggers, cuando necesito el ID del elemento borrado lo obtengo con OLD.id y hasta ahora no tuve problemas con ello. De todas formas, pruebo tu forma y te digo.

Comment: Nada, sigue sin funcionar. Asigno una especie con parámetros distintos a los que tiene el propio terrario y no funciona.

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir exactamente "no funciona"?

Comment: Pues que cuando inserto una especie dentro del terrario no cambian los valores del terrario

Comment: Si llamas manualmente al Stored Procedure, despu[es de haber hecho los cambios, ¿se actualizan los valores? o ¿quedan sin cambio? En caso de quedar sin cambio ¿devuelve los valores correctos si aislas el query con el que se hace el `update` y lo conviertes en un simple `select`?

Comment: Si llamo manualmente al stored procedure, poniendo por ejemplo el ID de terrario 4, que es el que uso para pruebas, no cambian sus valores, pero si, devuelve los valores correctos si aislo el query

Comment: Mmm, no me explico como eso podría pasar. Si ejecutas el update a mano, hay algún error?

Comment: No hay errores, simplemente no hace nada. También pensé que pudo ser por el safe update de MySQL, pero probe activándolo y desactivándolo y sigue en las mismas.

Comment: He hecho una prueba en https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e9QzvMjsF1sCzE3PiTD7xT/1 He asumido un par de cosas sobre tu estructura y he puesto los nombres de las entidades en singular y los ids llevan el nombre de la entidad, que son parte de mis reglas, y he puesto solo dos campos. Al final, el SP parece funcionar bien. Quizás el problema sea de confusión con nombres de campos, pero no es de sintaxis ni del principio de diseño.

Comment: ¿En qué difiere tu esquema? ¿Dejas un fiddle para echarle un ojo?

Comment: Disculpa por la espera, tuve un finde liadillo. Acabo de ver tu implementación en fiddle, he abierto MySQL, he probado el call al procedimiento y funciona a las mil perfecciones. No entiendo nada de por qué el otro día no funcionaba. Sea como fuere, funciona. ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Un gusto ser de alguna ayuda. Un saludo.